# ASP.NET 5 , wanted to separate entity framework from Web Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to achieve below application structure

App.Model
-- UserModel
-- OrderModel

App.Service
-- UserService
-- IUserService

App.Entity
-- DbContext

Website
-- WebAPI
   -- Invokes Service

Most of ASP.NET 5 application examples , initializes entity framework in startup file of website. like .AddEntityFrameowrk() .. etc.

Need to know how we can separate the Entity into separate project and how do we initiate the DBContext if we are invoking repository from Service project.( since startup file is not available for class library)

Comment: I believe as long as you are using the asp.net , you will need to initialise your services in the startup class, you can move AddEntityFrameowrk() to be part of method inside any project but at the end of the day you have to call it from the startup class

Comment: Does it mean Entity is tightly coupled with ASP.NET 5 ? There should be some way separation , since technology is new not able to find complete info about working flow .

Comment: EF is not tightly coupled to ASP.NET by any mean, it is just your question is about separating the EF in a project and still using it inside Web application, unless I got your question incorrectly

Comment: Yes you got it right. I dont want EF to be tightly bound with web application. I want Website to communicate to => webAPI => Service => EF .

Comment: Since asp.net web application is the entry point of the code, it will be responsible of initiating the application and this is done through the start class methods.

Answer (score 0):

In previous projects, I have taken the approach of maintaining multiple ASP.NET projects in one solution (or multiple solutions). This will give you the ability to remove the EF dependencies from your web application and have the web application talk only to the API which handles all the EF

In the past, I've created a dedicated 'domain' project which contains all the models and can be referenced by both your web application and API projects.

So the project structure would look like this

Domain project: Contains only c# classes that represent your model. Start with an 'empty' project

API: Contains your web API. Uses EF to interact with database. I would personally scaffold the APIs fro your model but that is a personal choice. Right now, in ASP.NET core 1.0 RC1, the web api template is poor so I'd start with the full 'web application' one and remove all the default views, controllers, scripts etc. References the domain project so that you can scaffold your API controllers from the model

Web Application: Your main web application project. Start with the 'web application' template but use HttpClient I your controller to use the api for data interactions. In the past I've created a set of static 'api helper classes' to make this task easier but that is a personal style choice again. References the domain project so that you can convert incoming JSON responses to the full .net model